# What exactly are the zonal services availability risks that PubSub Zonal Lite warns about?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, publish-subscribe, google-cloud-pubsub

While deciding between PubSub and PubSub Lite, I came across the point where it says "**... can work with availability risks inherent to zonal services?** Use zonal Lite topics".
Source at [Choosing Pub/Sub or Pub/Sub Lite](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/choosing-pubsub-or-lite#business_requirements_checklist).

What exactly are these availability risks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A regional service like Cloud Pub/Sub is resilient to individual zones being out because there are multiple zones in a region. Therefore, if one of those zones is unavailable for any reason, whether it be in Pub/Sub itself or any of its underlying internal dependencies, it should still behave as expected without any steps required on the part of the user.

On the other hand, a zonal service doesn't have that resiliency against a zonal outage: if the zone where your topic lives is unavailable, then that topic and its messages are unavailable until the zone recovers.